# How to extract data from JSON that meets a condition?

Tags: ruby, json

I have a `JSON file` and I would like to only get keys for all values that meet a condition. i.e (screen > 7%) and (jira > 8). The Following is the JSON file.

```
    {
  "screen": {
      "/theaters":            16.86,
      "/boxoffice":           12.87,
      "/theater/info":        11.07,
      "/theater/tickets":     7.00,
      "/TopBoxOffice":        4.34,
      "/upcoming":            4.02,
      "/new-releases":        3.49,
      "/trailer":             3.49,
      "/showtimes":           3.39,
      "/DvdOther":            3.13,
      "/MOB":                 2.85
  },

  "jira": {
      "theater":                      12,
      "showtime":                     11,
      "quantity":                     3,
      "card":                         4,
      "review":                       1,
      "confirm":                      1
    }

}
```

Output Should be something like:

```
screen = ["/theaters", "/boxoffice", "/theater/info"]
jira = ["theater", "showtime" ]
```

My current implementation looks like this:

```
file      = File.read('ga_jira.json')
data_hash = JSON.parse(file)
screen    = data_hash['screen']
jira      = data_hash['jira']

pp screen.select {|k,v| k > 7}
pp jira.select {|k,v| k > 7}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Tried something? How does it [not] work? Anyway, see [Hash#select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-select) (which can be trivially used once the JSON is parsed into a Ruby object-graph).

Comment: @user2864740 i have tried the following

Comment: `file = File.read('ga_jira.json')
    data_hash = JSON.parse(file)
    screen = data_hash['screen']
    jira = data_hash['jira']

    pp screen.select {|k,v| k > 7}
    pp jira.select {|k,v| k > 7}`

Comment: Thanks for the help. i meant above v>7 and v>8.

Comment: @napsterdsilva I've moved your comment into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see anything wrong in your usage. What do you get?

```
require 'json'

s = '{
 "screen": {
     "/theaters":            16.86,
  ...'

JSON.parse(s)['screen'].select{|k,v| v > 7 }
=> {"/theaters"=>16.86, "/boxoffice"=>12.87, "/theater/info"=>11.07}

JSON.parse(s)['jira'].select{|k,v| v > 7 }
=> {"theater"=>12, "showtime"=>11}

JSON.parse(s)['screen'].select{|k,v| v > 7 }.keys
=> ["/theaters", "/boxoffice", "/theater/info"]

JSON.parse(s)['jira'].select{|k,v| v > 7 }.keys
=> ["theater", "showtime"]
```

Comment: Close ;-) To get the desired output, you'll need to call `#keys` on the results, i.e. `screens.select{|_,v| v > 7}.keys` → `["/theaters", "/boxoffice", "/theater/info"]`

Comment: You are right. I didn't realise OP wanted the keys only.